# Confused about function subtyping

Tags: types, programming-languages, type-theory

I'm taking a course on programming languages and the answer to "when is a function a sub type of another function" is very counter-intuitive to me.

To clarify: suppose that we have the following type relation:

```
bool<int<real
```

Why is the function `(real->bool)` a subtype of `(int->bool`)? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

I would expect the criteria for sub typing functions to be: f1 is a subtype of f2 if f2 can take any argument that f1 can take, and f1 returns only values that f2 returns. There clearly are values that f1 can take, but f2 can't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the rule for function sub-typing:

**Argument types must be contra-variant, return types must be co-variant.**

Co-variant == preserves the "A is a subtype of B" hierarchy for the type of the results parameter.

Contra-variant == *reverses* ("goes against") the type hierarchy for the arguments parameter.

So, in your example:

```
f1:  int  -> bool
f2:  real -> bool
```

We can safely conclude that f2 is a subtype of f1.  Why?  Because (1) looking at just the argument types for both functions, we see that the type hierarchy of "bool is a subtype of int" is in fact co-variant.  It preserves the type hierarchy between ints and bools.  (2) looking at just the results types for both functions, we see that contra-variance is upheld.

Put another way (the plain English way I think about this subject):

contra-variant arguments:  "my caller can pass in *more* than I require, but that's okay, because I'll use only what I need to use."
co-variant return values:  "I can return *more* than the caller requires, but that's okay, he/she will just use what they need, and will ignore the rest"

Let's look at another examples, using structs where everything is an integer:

```
f1:  {x,y,z} -> {x,y}
f2:  {x,y}   -> {x,y,z}
```

So here again, we're asserting that f2 is a subtype of f1 (which it is).  Looking at the argument types for both functions (and using the < symbol to denote "is a subtype of"), then if f2 < f1, is {x,y,z} < {x,y} ?  The answer is yes.  {x,y,z} is co-variant with {x,y}.  i.e. in defining the struct {x,y,z} we "inherited" from the {x,y} struct, but added a third member, z.

Looking at the return types for both functions, if f2 < f1, then is {x,y} > {x,y,z}?  The answer again is yes.  (See above logic).

Yet a third way to think about this, is to assume f2 < f1, then try various casting scenarios, and see if everything works.  Example (psuedo-code):

```
   F1 = f1;
   F2 = f2;
   {a,b}   = F1({1,2,3});  // call F1 with a {x,y,z} struct of {1,2,3};  This works.
   {a,b,c} = F2({1,2});    // call F2 with a {x,y} struct of {1,2}.  This also works.
   
   // Now take F2, but treat it like an F1.  (Which we should be able to do, 
   // right?  Because F2 is a subtype of F1).  Now pass it in the argument type 
   // F1 expects.  Does our assignment still work?  It does.
   {a,b} = ((F1) F2)({1,2,3});
```

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was longer than I had hoped.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. If {x,y,z} is a subtype of {x,y}, why is bool a subtype of int? In the first case {x,y,z} is bigger than {x,y} yet in the other example bool is smaller than int.

Comment: Because you can cast an int into a bool.  (In most programming languages, anyway.  e.g. treat zero as false, all other integer values as true).

Comment: So basically subtyping is not about cardinality of its set of values? Meaning, it's not the same as a subset in the sense that a subtype's cardinality may be bigger than its superset's (as in the {x,y,z} vs {x,y} case) or smaller (as in the bool vs int case).

Comment: Don't focus on cardinality;  I think it'll only confuse you.  Focus on type hierarchy between two given types.  e.g. a bool can be said to be a subtype of an integer, because given an integer, I can reasonably cast it into a bool.  The reverse is not true.

Comment: It seems to me the answer to this question conflicts with a lot of the information out there.  subtyping means contravariant method parameters and covariant return types, doesn't it?  In other words, a General->Specific function would be a subtype of a Specific->General function (assuming Specific is a subtype of General).

Comment: Yes, you are right.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Function_types clearly says the opposite of of what I've written.  "the → type constructor is contravariant in the input type and covariant in the output type."  I will revisit and correct my answer shortly.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  This statement is backwards: "Argument types must be co-variant, return types must be contra-variant."  The answer by @dbmiikus is correct and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Now (finally) fixed.  Answer uses covariant and contravariant correctly.  Apologies, I am too busy for my own good.

Comment: our first example is still incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another answer because, while I understood how the function subtype rules made sense, I wanted to work through why any other combination of argument/result subtyping did not.

---

The subtype rule is:

[image: function subtyping rule]

Meaning that if the top subtype conditions are met, then the bottom holds true.

In the function type definition, the function **arguments are contravariant**, since we've reversed the subtype relation between `T1` and `S1`. The function **results are covariant** because they preserve the subtype relation between `T2` and `S2`.

With the definition out of the way, why is the rule like this? It's well stated in Aaron Fi's answer, and I also found the definition [here](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~msagiv/courses/apl12/subtyping.pdf) (search for the heading "Function Types"):

> An alternative view is that it is safe to allow a function of one type
>   `S1 → S2` to be used in a context where another type `T1 → T2` is expected
>   as long as none of the arguments that may be passed to the function in this context will surprise it (`T1 <: S1`) and none of the results that it returns will surprise the context (`S2 <: T2`).

Again, that made sense to me, but I wanted to see why no other combination of typing rules made sense. To do this I looked at a simple higher order function and some example record types.

For all examples below, let:

1. `S1 := {x, y}`
2. `T1 := {x, y, z}`
3. `T2 := {a}`
4. `S2 := {a, b}`

#### Example with contravariant argument types and covariant return types

Let:

1. `f1` have type `S1 → S2 ⟹ {x, y} → {a, b}`
2. `f2` have type `T1 → T2 ⟹ {x, y, z} → {a}`

Now assume that `type(f1) <: type(f2)`. We know this from the rule above, but let's pretend we don't and just see why it makes sense.

We run `map( f2 : {x, y, z} → {a}, L : [ {x, y, z} ] ) : [ {a} ]`

If we replace `f2` with `f1` we get:

```
map( f1 : {x, y} → {a, b}, L : [ {x, y, z} ] ) : [ {a, b} ]
```

This works out fine because:

1. Whatever the function `f1` does with its argument, it can ignore the extra `z` record field and have no problems.
2. Whatever the context running `map` does with the results, it can ignore
   the extra `b` record field and have no problems.

Concluding:

```
{x, y} → {a, b} ⟹ {x, y, z} → {a} ✔
```

#### Example with covariant argument types and covariant return types

Let:

1. `f1` have type `T1 → S2 ⟹ {x, y, z} → {a, b}`
2. `f2` have type `S1 → T2 ⟹ {x, y} → {a}`

Assume `type(f1) <: type(f2)`

We run `map( f2 : {x, y} → {a}, L : [ {x, y} ] ) : [ {a} ]`

If we replace `f2` with `f1` we get:

```
map( f1 : {x, y, z} → {a, b}, L : [ {x, y} ] ) : [ {a, b} ]
```

We can run into a problem here because `f1` expects and might operate on the `z` record field, and such a field is not present in any records in list `L`. ⚡

#### Example with contravariant argument types and contravariant return types

Let:

1. `f1` have type `S1 → T2 ⟹ {x, y} → {a}`
2. `f2` have type `T1 → S2 ⟹ {x, y, z} → {a, b}`

Assume `type(f1) <: type(f2)`

We run `map( f2 : {x, y, z} → {a, b}, L : [ {x, y, z} ] ) : [ {a, b} ]`

If we replace `f2` with `f1` we get:

```
map( f1 : {x, y} → {a}, L : [ {x, y, z} ] ) : [ {a} ]
```

We have no issue with ignoring the `z` record field when passed into `f1`, but if the context that calls `map` expects the a list of records with a `b` field, we will hit an error. ⚡

#### Example with covariant argument types and contravariant return

Look at the above examples for the two places this could go wrong.

### Conclusion

This is a very long and verbose answer, but I had to jot this stuff down to figure out why other argument and return parameter subtyping was invalid. Since I had it somewhat written down, I figured why not post it here.

Comment: Thank you, I was confused by the accepted answer because he seems to be using the correct logic but opposing terms.

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling finding my own answer to this same question because I did not find it *intuitive* by just accepting the substitution rules. So here is my attempt:

By definition: function `f1: A1 => B1` is a *supertype* of `f2: A2 => B2` if `f2` can be used in places that require `f1`.

Now look at the following diagram, imagine water flows from top to bottom through funnels `f1` and `f2`.

[image]

We realize that if we want to replace the funnel `f1` with another funnel `f2`, then:

- Input diameter `A2` must be *no smaller* than `A1`.
- Output diameter `B2` needs to be *no bigger* than `B1`.

The same reasoning applies to functions: in order for `f2` to be able to replace `f1`, then:

- Input set `A2` of `f2` needs to cover all possible inputs of `f1`, i.e. `A1` <: `A2`, and
- Output set `B2` of `f2` needs to fit in what is required for `f1`, i.e. `B2` <: `B1`

To put it another way: If `A1` <: `A2` and `B1` >: `B2` then `f1: A1 => B1` >: `f2: A2 => B2`

Comment: a picture paints a thousand words :) <3

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered, but I'd like to present here an easy example (regarding the argument type, which is the unintuitive one).

The below code **will fail**, because you can pass only Strings to `myFuncB`,
and we are passing numbers and booleans.

```
typedef FuncTypeA = Object Function(Object obj); // (Object) => Object
typedef FuncTypeB = String Function(String name); // (String) => String

void process(FuncTypeA myFunc) {
   myFunc("Bob").toString(); // Ok.
   myFunc(123).toString(); // Fail.
   myFunc(true).toString(); // Fail.
}

FuncTypeB myFuncB = (String name) => name.toUpperCase();

process(myFuncB);
```

However, the below code **will work**, because now you can pass objects of any type to `myFuncB`,
and we only pass Strings.

```
typedef FuncTypeA = Object Function(String name); // (String) => Object
typedef FuncTypeB = String Function(Object obj); // (Object) => String

void process(FuncTypeA myFuncA) {
   myFunc("Bob").toString(); // Ok.
   myFunc("Alice").toString(); // Ok.
}

FuncTypeB myFuncB = (Object obj) => obj.toString();

process(myFuncB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from TAPL:

**S** is a subtype of **T**, i.e., **S <: T** if any term of type **S** can be used in a context where a term of type **T** is expected. Applying this to function subtyping **F <: G** means any function of type **F** can be used in a context where a function of type **G** is expected.

Other intuitions of subtyping are:

> 1. every value described by **S** is also described by **T**

> 2. the elements of **S** are a subset of elements of **T**

Let's use intuition **2.** for the following function subtyping to check when is it safe to use $ S_1 \to S_2 $ in a context where $ T_1 \to T_2$ is expected.

[image]

In order to be compatible with the expected function $ T_1 \to T_2$, we can immediately   see that the arguments $ S_1 $ should be a `superset` of $ T_1 $, i.e., all required arguments should definitely be present, extra arguments can be present, we can simply not process the extra arguments;  and the return values $ S_2 $ should be `subset` of $ T_2 $ in order to not surprise the context where $ T_1 \to T_2$ is generally invoked / applied.