# Dart: Function X is NOT a subtype of Function Y

Tags: types, dart

In Dart, if:

`MyWidget` is of type `Widget`.

Then why:

`(BuildContext, ViewModel) => MyWidget`

is **not** a subtype of:

`(BuildContext, dynamic) => Widget` ?

And how do I fix this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150372/confused-about-function-subtyping.

Comment: @JonahWilliams This link perfectly answers my question. I'm coming from Java, where I never really had to think about function subtyping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `dynamic` is a super-type of `ViewModel`, so a function accepting `(BuildContext, ViewModel)` as argument can't be used where a function accepting `(BuildContext, dynamic)` is required. The latter can be called with second arguments that are no `ViewModel` instances.

So, the problem is in the arguments, not in the return type.